# Probability of k nodes at a certain level.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

As this is homework I do not wan't a complete solution, just pointers where to look :)

given there are $n$ persons at the bottom of a building, level 0. 
what is the probability that $k$ persons reach level $i$. $k = 0,1,...,n$ 
At each floor a  person flips a coin if heads i he moves to the next floor.

I just only figured out the probablity for the first floor. ${n \choose k}/{2^n}$

The thing is when I "reach" the second floor what the probability will be for $1$ person reaching the second floor.

For two persons starting at the bottom floor.

$S  = \{rr, ss, rs, sr\}$, s = stay, r = reach

$P_1(rr) = 1/4$ both reach first floor

$P_1(rs, sr) = 2/4$ One reach

$P_1(ss) = 1/4$ no one reaches

The part I'm getting wrong probably.

$P_2(ss) = P_1(ss) + 1/2*P_1(rs, sr) + 1/2*P_1(rr) = 1/4 + 1/4+1/8 = 5/8$

I need to arrive to a general formula for calculating the probability for k persons recaching ith floor.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What are the rules governing whether a person "reaches" some level or other? Your formula involves $r$ which is not defined...

Comment: @lulu you're correct! I added the rules, each person flips a coin and if heads he or she reaches the next floor. :) 

I also specieified what i have been trying out with two persons to see if my approach is on the right track :)

Comment: So, just to be sure, each person tosses the coin until a $T$ appears, and if they get $H^jT$ they stop on floor $j$, yes?  If so then the probability of an individual stopping on floor $j$ is $p_j=2^{-(j+1)}$ and you can do your problem by treating this  as bernouilli trials with probability $p_j$.

Comment: unless by "reaching floor k" you meant "stops on floor j for $j≥k$".  If that's what you you meant, Bernouilli trials still work but you need to correct the probability.

Comment: @lulu It's exactly what I was looking for, each person flips a coin until getting a tails then stops at the floor $i$ as stated in your second comment :) I will look into bernoulli trials! thanks alot, we were told that it was able to solve without getting ahead to the next lecture were bernoulli is gonna be explained, I think we were misinformed! :) Thanks again!